Scalability Limits of Microsoft Bot Framework Apps Built with Application-hosted media?
Background: A call answering voicebot built with Microsoft Bot Framework and with Application-hosted media. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/requirements-considerations-application-hosted-media-bots )
We have a SIP address associated with the bot and thence a phone number via the Teams Admin/ Azure portal
The bot answers the calls from Teams users as well as PSTN users.    All this is working fine.
Are there any design or policy level scalability limits on Microsoft Bot Framework Apps  built with Application-hosted media on the Teams side?  (Not asking about compute/network resources of the machine running the bot)
For example, are there any upper design or policy limits on number of calls Teams will allow to be terminated to the single phone number associated with the bot?
Similar question about any limits on the number of simultaneous calls made by Teams users to the bot?  (also considering a front end ACS app)
Our design goals is to support 250 simultaneous calls to the voice bot between PSTN users and Teams Users calling in to the bot.
If you have built bots using these techniques would be interested in feedback on scalability.
How many simultaneous users were you able to support? How did you test your simultaneous user load?
Thanks
